# Batch script for checking file size - Error message

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a batch file that is intended to check file size but results in an error message that says, "3072 unexpected at this time". Here is the code:

```
rem @echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set minbytesize=3072

if %~z1 LSS %minbytesize%
    echo.failed
ELSE
    echo.passed
```

The batch file is executed from another piece of software with a Windows "call" command and passes the file name to this batch as %1 parameter.  The addition of ~z in the &1 parameter does resolve to the file size.

I have experimented with different combinations of ", %, and ! in the "if" line but nothing has been successful yet.  Any ideas on what else could be missing?

Comment: @KraangPrime - That is totally useless advice, and has nothing to do with the error. The ENDLOCAL is not required.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two unrelated problems in that short bit of code that can yield two different errors.

Assuming you pass in a valid file parameter, then you will get this error message: ***The syntax of the command is incorrect.*** That is because your IF syntax is wrong. If you want the IF command to span multiple lines, then you must use parentheses (or line continuation, but that is less commonly used).

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set minbytesize=3072

if %~z1 LSS %minbytesize% (
    echo.failed
) else (
    echo.passed
)
```

But you still have problems if you forget to provide the file argument, or if the file does not exist. In that case, the `%~1` expands to an empty string, so the command becomes:

```
if  LSS 3072 (
```

which is invalid syntax that generates: ***3072 was unexpected at this time.*** That error message is received because `LSS` is interpreted as the left side of the comparison, after which the parser is expecting a comparison operator, but sees `3072` instead.

Perhaps the simplest method do resolve this problem is to store the value of `%~1` in a variable, and then if the variable is undefined, set the value to 0.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set minbytesize=3072
set size=%~z1
if not defined size set size=0

if %size% LSS %minbytesize% (
    echo.failed
) else (
    echo.passed
)
```

Comment: I knew it had to be something simple but stared at it so long I was just drawing blanks.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. @dbenham your advice was just what I needed. Everything works great now.